# Unity app stops background music

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-music-player

My android app made with unity 5.3.4p1 pausing background music. I start play music with some player on my android device, but when I launch my app, after splash screen that music stops, and only music from the game starts and continue playing. This happens on different devices. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the normal behaviour of most android players to stop music when app is in background. Probably not unity related.

Comment: same player continue playing music with other apps

Comment: I have the same issue. I think it's a unity bug in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this sequence:

1. In Unity 5, go to File > Build Settings and select Android Platform.
2. After that click on Player Settings and your Inspector will open Android publish preferences.
3. In the tab Other Settings, uncheck the option "Mute Other Audio Sources"

This might be work!